# Expand a column holding iterables into rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Say I have a DataFrame like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'baz': ['yes','fine'], 'foo': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['s', 'r']]}, 
                   index=['W1', 'W2'])

> df
     baz        foo
W1   yes   [a, b, c]
W2   fine     [s, r]
```

How can I expand the column `foo`? The result should be, in this case:

```
> df
    baz  foo
W1  yes    a
    yes    b
    yes    c
W2  fine   s
    fine   r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebuild a DataFrame by extracting values and recreating index:

```
result = []
[result.extend(zip(([df.baz[i]])*len(df.foo[i]), df.foo[i])) for i in range(len(df.baz))]
index = [[df.index[i]]*len(df.foo[i]) for i in range(len(df.baz))]
index = [item for sublist in index for item in sublist] # flatten 

final = pd.DataFrame(result,index=index, columns = df.columns) # final result
```

result will be:

```
   baz foo
W1   y   a
W1   y   b
W1   y   c
W2   z   s
W2   z   r
```

Comment: I updated the code and it does exactly what you wanted

Comment: Thanks! It seems to break when the column holding singles has a regular string. See my edits to the OP.

Comment: fixed by treating elements in the first column as a list. It now works with both your previous and current testcases